# Datastudio chart - data reusability

Tags: looker-studio

In my google data studio report, I have multiple (over 10) charts are using the same data source (my custom community connector to access my platform to get data).  When I view the data studio report, it makes 1 call for each chart.

Is there any settings within the datastudio to re-use the same data set by calling my data source once per report (instead of once per chart) to reduce the call to my platform?

I would like to explore possibility of using data studio default configuration before I proceed to develop cache mechanism in my custom community connector.

Comment: Which custom community do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Data Studio caches some data, but most of the time it is one call per chart.

Maybe consider to export your historical data to Big Query?

The community connector can also cache data. So if Data Studio sends the same request for each chart shorty after, the connector only has to return the data from its cache. Be aware that if the charts have different fields, each request is different.

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache-service